# Is there a way with Git or Python to see all the dependencies between the selected files?

Tags: python, git, github

The goal is to PR a lot of code into a beta branch of our application on github. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to do this.

Say I had a function or process called X and in order for X to be functional it needs all of these files:

```
hello.py
x.py
test.py
run.py
example.py
whatever.py
```

The above are just random example files I made up, but imagine a process or function requiring many files to work.

So obviously, my intuition is just to remove some files while keeping others together that makes the best sense. I then run a test script and see if I get any import errors.

I'm strictly just adding and removing files, I'm not editing any code.

Currently I'm using git checkout, git diff, and git status to do this work and choosing files based on what I think makes sense, but I feel as if this is inefficient.

I'll then merge the branches with beta and continue forward like below:
[image]

Can anyone recommend python, git methods, other techniques, or a mindset that would help me untangle this web of code into good bite size pieces of code?
Is there a way with Git or Python to see all the dependencies between the selected files shown above?

Comment: Git pays no attention whatsoever to the files it is storing (well, *almost* no attention, there are `.gitmodules` and `.gitignore` files for instance). So Git alone can't do any of this. And, removing files isn't going to work in the general case as Python's `import xxx` searches for anything that provides module `xxx` in the Python-dependent search path: if the file that does provide `xxx` in the provided tree is gone, Python might find some *other* file instead!

Comment: So, what you want here is something that *understands Python* (to whatever extent you care to take this) and looks for `import` directives. In general, that would be a Python debugger.